# Getting Public SSH key of clients Computer

Tags: node.js, github, ssh-keys

How do I get client's Public SSH key like the GitHub may do for push verification in NodeJS?
OR
How GitHub verify client's computer while making a push?

Answer (score 0):

Each git service will require you to create and register an SSH key, that you will have to use when interacting with the service.  There's usually a page walking you through the process.   Here's github's [link:https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/)

Comment: Thanks sir but i think you didn't get my question: Like When we login to facebook if we allow we are giving it our location info, os info likewise is there any way to get public ssh keys